# cache/flush-schema command for specific database connection in yii2-advanced

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm running the `yii cache/flush-schema` command on the root of yii-advanced project but it's working on only one and default `db` connection.  Whereas, the application is having multiple database connections and I need to run the command on specific database.

Answer (score 0):

Running the command with specifying the database connection name in it, would do the job, as:

```
yii cache/flush-schema db_connection_name
```